# How to create and access a numpy array of Objects?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I think my code will explain what I'm trying to do:

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self, Author, Pages):
        self.Author = Author
        self.Pages  = Pages
    def getAuthor(self):
        return self.Author

book_1 = Book("Jane Smith", 20)
book_2 = Book("Billy", 20)


B = np.array([book_1, book_2])
print(B[0][1].getAuthor())
```

Basically, I want to this to print "Billy", the error I am getting is:
`TypeError: 'Book' object is not subscriptable`

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: What do you think `B[0][1]` is doing? Please explain in excruciating detail

Comment: I fixed the issue, I assumed you always had to reference the first row even in a 1 x 2 matrix. Thanks for your good faith comment :)))

Comment: You can always check your array dimentions by using np.shape, in your example B.shape :)

Comment: You don't have a 1x2 matrix.  You have a length 2 matrix, where each element is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy (unlike MATLAB) does not add dimensions to an array that you don't tell it to. So, `B = np.array([book_1, book_2])` creates an array of shape `(2,)`, not `(2, 1)` or `(1, 2)`. You can verify this by printing `B.shape`.

To access the second element, you just do `B[1]`.

When you do `B[0][1]`, you are accessing the first element, and then indexing it with `[1]`, as if you did `book_1[1]`. The error is telling you that that is illegal because you did not implement `__getitem__` in your class.

**Notes:**

- You generally don't want to use numpy for object arrays. They offer no advantages over `list`, and some disadvantages when it comes to appending elements.
- Indexing a multidimensional numpy array is done via a single index (unlike a list, which only supports one dimension at a time). So if `B` really was 2D, you would do `B[0, 1]`. While you *could* do `B[0][1]`, it actually does something a bit different than `B[0, 1]`. `B[0]` is a view of the first row of the array. `B[0][1]` is an element of that view. This will generally be in the same buffer as the original, but depending on the memory layout and the type of indexing you use, the two approaches may have surprisingly different results.